# Legal basis for remaining face mask mandate in the NHS, UK

Tags: united-kingdom, covid-19

In the UK, all legal mask mandates have been dropped. However from what I understand, they are still required “in healthcare settings”. This could be in a hospital, doctor’s surgery or a pharmacy.

It is not clear, however, what legal basis those remaining mask mandates have. Searching online I find a whole bunch of information, but noting specifically addressing this point.

Could someone please definitively answer whether the remaining mask rules are advisory or mandatory?

If they are mandatory, please cite under which law?

Comment: I dont see that this page cites a paragraph from a lawbook, still it's an official site: https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/face-coverings-when-to-wear-one-and-how-to-make-your-own/face-coverings-when-to-wear-one-and-how-to-make-your-own

Comment: @BernhardDöbler Thanks. That leads to https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/wuhan-novel-coronavirus-infection-prevention-and-control/covid-19-guidance-for-maintaining-services-within-health-and-care-settings-infection-prevention-and-control-recommendations, which has “guidance” at the top, So as a follow-up question, does this guidance have any statute law behind it; or it is just advisory?